# Efficiently painting a custom QGraphicsItem

Tags: pyqt4, qgraphicsitem

I have a custom QGraphicsItem which has a QPainterPath as member.

As the mouse is dragged, the movement is traced onto this path. 
The paint() method in the QGrahicsItem draws the whole path. 
The purpose of implementing this is, the whole path is drawn to an image when the mouse is released (The image needs to be free for other drawing as long as possible, so can't directly draw on it).

The issue here is, as the path gets longer, the updating of graphics on QGraphicsScene gets visibly slower.

Is there a way to optimize and speed up the paint() method, while keeping the the path which can be directly drawn to an image?